# Selenium - Xpath locate elements with different IDs

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, tags

I am trying to locate element which may have different ID at times. 
Here is the example :

```
id = 'greenbay_packers"
id = "Sf_49ers"
```

Now, is there a way do to some kind of OR operation in find_element method? so that I can use same element locator for test steps?

Also if this is not possible, is there a way to write fail safe routine that try to locate using find_element(:`id,'greenbay_packaers"`) but if fails try find_element(:`id,'sf_49ers`"). And only fail test if above 2 are not found.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with `or`

```
//*[(@id='test1') or (@id='test2')]
```

For second part,
I would suggest you to try `try..catch..finally` since you have only two conditions to match

```
try
{
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID1"));
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
{
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID1"));
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed");
}
```

*Written in C#*